# Minify Js and CSS files using Nginx and angular 1

Tags: javascript, css, angular, nginx, minify

I have my backend server in django rest framework and front end in angular 1. I have nginx installed on aws ec2 which redirects request to corresponding server. Nginx also takes care of front end repo. I have git as version control system for front end. Now, I want to minify all the css and js files in my front end code. I want to know the best practice to do that. Since for front end I just used to specify my source directory in nginx, so I don't have any build system or build directory for front end. Since, I have read we don't push minify files in github, then how to do that.

Comment: "the correct procedure" - there are a number of ways to do it, there is no "correct procedure", at most, there is best practice but still no accurate answer can be given. Minifying is done during the build process usually, after fetching the sources and before the deploying. Please be more specific otherwise this question is off-topic or too broad.

Comment: @DanFromGermany thanks for your comment, I edited the question.May you guide me in this?

Comment: There is no specific programing problem in your question. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

nginx doesn't minify files on it's own, you need to use third party minification. Here are starting points:

- [Using PERL](https://github.com/nginx-modules/nginx-minify)
- [Using PHP](https://www.newmediacampaigns.com/blog/Automatic-file-minification-on-nginx)

Comment: how to add it in the build procedure?

Comment: This wouldn't be part of the build process but would require to be set up on the live server. The instructions are in the links. If you want to minify code during the build process, you would need something like https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2 and either run it through the command line or as part of a build process with for example NPM or gulp.js. This depends on how you would like to setup your build process.

Comment: Usually you don't minifiy on the fly. What if there is an error in your files or during the process, then all your live website is defect. You don't do this if you are a serious developer.

Comment: That's true, ideally you would just set up a CI system that takes care of the minification once the unminified code is pushed to GIT. Unfortunately OP didn't elaborate very much on his setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using grunt.

[Grunt](https://gruntjs.com/)

And how to use grunt with angularjs - you can find out here:  [How to use grunt in angular](http://angularjshowtos.blogspot.in/2014/10/use-grunt-to-minify-your-angularjs-files.html)

And Most importantly, right now you have only requirement of css, and js mini faction but this can be used for much more. 
For css minification , https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin
and for js, https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify